# Having trouble configuring C++ MySQL API in XCode

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode, api

I am trying to configure C++ MySQL API in Xcode. I followed the instruction that the teacher provide us, first downloaded and installed the MySQL community server and Connector for C. I also edit Project setting:

```
Search Paths - Header Search Paths
/usr/local/mysql/include
Search Paths - Library Search Paths
/usr/local/mysql/lib
Linking - Other Linker Flags
-lmysqlclient
-lm
-lz
```

However, when I ran the code:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "", "project3-nudb", 0, 0, 0);

    if (connection == NULL)
    {
        //unable to connect
        printf("Oh Noes!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You are now connected. Welcome!\n");
    }
}
```

It kept showing "Oh Noes!\n" which indicate unable to connect. In the instruction slide, it also states:

In the terminal: (this step is important or the project can not find libmysqlclient.18.dylib)

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

I have tried the first line and don't quite know whats the second line mean. Since I look up the path /usr/lib/, there's no such file in the directory. I also tried to copy /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib to /usr/lib/ but still not working.

Could someone tell me what step I got wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you're aware, this is the clunky old C connector, not [the C++ one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/).

Comment: @tadman I was also confused that why our teacher ask us to install the c connector but provide the c++ test code. Thank you!

Comment: The C++ one has a lot more in the way of convenience features. The C one is really, really old and ugly. Hope you can use the C++ one.